# How to implement lateinit properly with custom class objects for use in onCreate() in android avoiding 'Property getter or setter expected' error

Tags: android, kotlin, oncreate, kotlin-null-safety, kotlin-lateinit

I am trying to implement the integration of a Dialogflow (previously api.ai) agent with my Android app, using Kotlin. I checked other Q&A about kotlin `lateinit` and the onCreate() lifecycle in Android is ideal for late-init implementations, to avoid writing dirty code with null objects and corresponding `!!` and `?` accesses in Kotlin. But I am running into the error of '**Property getter or setter expected**' when trying to `lateinint` instances of self-defined class. Here is the code:

```
class AIApplication : Application() {

    private var activitiesCount: Int = 0

    var lateinit settingsManager: SettingsManager
        //private set

    private val isInForeground: Boolean
        get() = activitiesCount > 0

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        settingsManager = SettingsManager(this)
    }
```

Which gives me the error of '**Property getter or setter expected**' on the `lateinit settingsManager` line. Here is the `SettingsManager` definition:

```
class SettingsManager(private val context: Context) {
    private val prefs: SharedPreferences

    private var useBluetooth: Boolean = false

    var isUseBluetooth: Boolean
        get() = useBluetooth
        set(useBluetooth) {
            this.useBluetooth = useBluetooth

            prefs.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USE_BLUETOOTH, useBluetooth).commit()
            val controller = (context.applicationContext as AIApplication).getBluetoothController()
            if (useBluetooth) {
                controller!!.start()
            } else {
                controller!!.stop()
            }
        }

    init {
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        useBluetooth = prefs.getBoolean(PREF_USE_BLUETOOTH, true)
    }

    companion object {

        private val SETTINGS_PREFS_NAME = "ai.api.APP_SETTINGS"
        private val PREF_USE_BLUETOOTH = "USE_BLUETOOTH"
    }

}
```

So what is the proper way to do this? Do I need to make some changes to the SettingsManager class? Please explain the whole concept clearly.

Comment: try changing it to public

Comment: @SarthakGandhi which modifier exactly are you asking me to make public?

Comment: i guess you are declaring var isUseBluetooth: Boolean twice.

Comment: From the code i can see that is the main error.

Comment: @SarthakGandhi one is '`useBluetooth`' and the other is '`isUseBluetooth`', not the same. Besides I am not getting any error from that class. I am getting error from the 1st code snippet: `AIApplication`.

Comment: private  var  settingsManager: SettingsManager? = null try this.

Comment: ohhh i found the error the syntax of declaring lateinit is lateinit var settingsManager:SettingsManager not var lateinit.

Comment: @SarthakGandhi yes, i can use `var settingsManager: SettingsManager? = null`, but that means I would have to manually use `!!` and `?` to call the object, which means no more automatic null protection of kotlin.

Comment: you are declaring it wrong use this  lateinit var settingsManager:SettingsManager

Comment: @SarthakGandhi yes, that fixed the problem, nice observation! You can post an answer saying this, using some code, so it doesn't get autoconverted to chat, then I will accept that as the answer so you can get the credit. Thanks!

Comment: Sure i have posted this as an answer. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lateinit declaration of the SettingsManager is wrong. Try this :

```
lateinit var settingsManager: SettingsManager
```

instead of

```
var lateinit settingsManager: SettingsManager
```

Hope this helps.